# El Capitan auto-corrects even though I turned it off in settings

Tags: keyboard, macos, autocorrect

I notice that things are being corrected even when I turn spell-check off. This happened on both of my computers, and particularly stupid spelling corrections are taking place, only since upgrading to El Capitan.

Example.. I updated a ticket at work "This is now on production" .. when I submit the update, I see it says "This is not on production" ...

At first I thought maybe I did a typo but this keeps happening.

Every single instance was where the word is actually spelled correctly however it replaces it with another word.

I've turned spell-check off so I am confused as to why it's doing it at all.

Comment: Grrrr - it's a pain when you can't change something like that. Is the issue something reproducible in a new user account? My guess is a preference file is corrupt or some rare filesystem errors, but that's a hunch and not a given.

Comment: Check there isn't another pref set in the app you're using. I have spellcheck off in prefs/keyboard but on in Safari [tbh, I'm not really sure what the global pref is supposed to 'fix' as it doesn't carry to Safari/TextEdit etc]

Comment: it's a pain that Apple software seems to consistently have problems with not being able to 'upgrade' to new OS. I don't like to start from scratch and have to take 50 hours to set up my stuff every time I upgrade to a new OS. I had a similar issue with iPhone but the issue was much more severe, and other people said too they didn't have the problem. When I started from scratch on new phone and lost everything in my apps and games, then it worked fine.

Comment: I'm using system preferences Tetsujin. Interesting though I'm using Chrome. Maybe Chrome has its own thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is only place to disable spell check in `System Preferences` and on doing that it works fine for me on `El Capitan`. Can you try enabling and disabling again and probably a reboot to see if it helps.

[image]

Comment: Every app also has its own place to regulate this, in Edit > Spelling and Grammar